# Spring Batch Job + Spring Cloud Data Flow UI

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-admin

Our application is built using Spring boot + Gradle. We have got a new requirement to implement spring batch job and it will be triggered using autosys(job scheduling tool) and it has 3 steps performing 3 different operations (file preparation, ftp & audit operations). I have attached @EnableBatchProcessing configuration file for your reference. Here are my questions related to Spring Cloud Data Flow.

1. Can Spring cloud data flow project be built using Gradle ?. I see all the sample projects built using Maven and official Spring page says Maven is must for Spring Cloud Data Flow. Gradle is the only approved build project in our company.
2. We are looking for Spring batch admin UI kind of features or operations in Spring Cloud data flow. May i know how can i configure Jobs in Spring Cloud data flow? any sample project?
3. Our application is deployed into PCF(Pivotal Cloud Foundry) container. So the question is, Do we need to add any services/plugins/space must be allocated in PCF infrastructure to support Spring Cloud data flow ?...
4. Is Spring Cloud data flow project production ready ?. can this be used in Production?.

```
     @Configuration   
     @EnableBatchProcessing     
     public class TaskletsConfig {

     @Autowired   
     private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

     @Autowired   
     private StepBuilderFactory steps;

     @Bean   
     protected Step flatFilePreparation() {    
         return steps
                 .get("flatFilePreparation")
                 .tasklet(new FlatFilePreparation())
                 .build();
     }

     @Bean
     protected Step ftpFile() {
         return steps
                 .get("ftpFile")
                 .tasklet(new FtpFile())
                 .build();
     }

     @Bean
     protected Step auditFilePreparation() {
         return steps
                 .get("auditFilePreparation")
                 .tasklet(new AuditFilePreparation())
                 .build();
     }

     @Bean
     protected Step errorStep() {
         return steps
                 .get("errorStep")
                 .tasklet(new ErrorStep())
                 .build();
     }

     @Bean
     public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("psbijob").start(flatFilePreparation()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(errorStep())
             .from(flatFilePreparation()).on("*").to(ftpFile()).on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(errorStep())    
             .from(ftpFile()).on("*").to(auditFilePreparation()).end().build();      
     }

     @Bean    
     public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {    
         MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory
                 = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();    
         factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());    
         return (JobRepository) factory.getObject();    
     }    

     @Bean    
     public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {    
         return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();    
     }    

     @Bean    
     public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {    
         SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();    
         jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());    
         return jobLauncher;    
     }    
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to unpack the questions.

> Can Spring cloud data flow project be built using Gradle?

All that Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) requires to create and launch your batch-job is a Spring Boot App (a uber-jar). It doesn't matter whether or not you build the application with Maven, Gradle or by other custom means. Docker is another popular choice and that's the only choice for Kubernetes. In PCF, we recommend the use of maven artifacts, which you can, of course, produce it with Gradle, too.

> We are looking for Spring batch admin UI kind of features or operations in Spring Cloud data flow. May i know how can i configure Jobs in Spring Cloud data flow? any sample project?

I'd suggest that you explore the [Dashboard](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard) section in the reference guide. Also, we have an end-to-end Task and [Batch Developer Guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/) in the SCDF Microsite. Anything and everything you did in Spring Batch Admin can be entirely covered in SCDF, and a lot more features sit on top of it, too. Please take a moment to at least review what all are included.

> Do we need to add any services/plugins/space must be allocated in PCF infrastructure to support Spring Cloud data flow?

No special requirement. SCDF is simply just a Boot app, too. You can push it manually to your Org/Space or use the [SCDF Tile for PCF](https://docs.pivotal.io/scdf/1-4/) (a fully managed marketplace service) to provision SCDF and the related components (Security / Upgrades / DB / Broker) automatically.

> Is Spring Cloud data flow project production ready ?. can this be used in Production?

The 1.0 GA of SCDF was released back in July 2016. We are currently at 2.1 GA version. There have been 50+ production releases since the first GA milestone. The SCDF tile for PCF is in production for >1yr now also. And, in PCF specifically, we have several customers using SCDF in production.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sabby Anandan. But i have further questions on this. If i want to point SCDF to our application DB to preserve the job execution details, how do i do that ?. i guess we need to create simple MS with SCDF dependencies and point to SQL server. am i correct ?. if yes, can this simple MS built using gradle ?. i saw few examples online using maven build.

Comment: further on this topic, I have tried to download sping cloud data flow jar and ran in my local, i was able to open the dashboard, configure task and was able to run it. But it doesnt show any job details ?. how do i see entries in job section where i want to start, stop or restart the job?.

Comment: Task/Batch apps in SCDF _requires_ an RDBMS for state and persistence. Without that, you cannot run batch-jobs. Again, please have a look at ref. guide / microsite - we invest efforts to document it all for the users to gain understanding.

Comment: It is hard to continue the discussion in the comments. It is not very easy to unpack all the details here. Since you're an already PCF customer, perhaps you can open a support ticket? One of the platform architects from Pivotal can coordinate a meeting to clarify all this more easily.